# Is there a way to show max amount items in masonry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

Is there a way to show a max amount of items in jQuery Masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/#jquery

We want to show max 12 items on http://denimjacket.nl/voorbeeld-pagina/, so we would like to hide the rest. We can show max 12 items with a Wordpress function, but ofcourse the Masonry will then only work on those 12 items, which is not correct. It has to work on all items, but still show max 12 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the surrounding container style overflow: hidden; and you can also set the height of the surrounding container.

Comment: Great thinking! I will try that tonight! I'll let you if it works or not.